# Delay adding a class for 2 seconds in hover()

Tags: jquery

How do I use easing or time delay on `addClass();`?

```
$("#date_1").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("door");
        $(this).addClass("doorstatic", "slow"); // after 2seconds i want to add this class during the hover
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("door");
        $(this).removeClass("doorstatic"); // both classes are instantly removed when hover off
    }
);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$("#date_1").hover(   
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.addClass("door");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.addClass("doorstatic");
        }, 2000); // 2000 is in mil sec eq to 2 sec.
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("door doorstatic");
    }
);
```

You can group your classes like `removeClass("door doorstatic")`

The problem here is that if you mouseover and before two seconds mouse out you will still have the class `doorstatic` on you element.

The fix:

```
$("#date_1").hover(    
    function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            timer = $this.data("timer") || 0;

        clearTimeout(timer);
        $this.addClass("door");

        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $this.addClass("doorstatic");
        }, 2000); // 2000 is in mil sec eq to 2 sec.

        $this.data("timer", timer);
    },
    function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            timer = $this.data("timer") || 0;

        clearTimeout(timer);
        $this.removeClass("door doorstatic");
    }
);
```

Created a live example of the solution at **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3r4A/)**.

Comment: The "doorstatic" class will probably be added 2 seconds after hover (mouse enter) even if you choose to remove the mouse (mouse leave) before those 2 seconds.

Comment: But I have several.. I have a calendar basically and there are boxes in a row.. the user may use the mouse and flow over many ... there is more than one box next to eac other on page..

Comment: Nice! Really like the use of `data()` and the `||` operator :)

Comment: It should work on several elements as he´s storing the timer on/together with the current(this) element. You´ll have to use a new selector for the hover event though.

Answer (score 2):

The `setTimeout` method of javascript can be used to run code you specify after a set delay in miliseconds.

Try this:

```
var timeout;
$("#date_1").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass("door");
        timeout = setTimeout(function() { $(this).addClass("doorstatic"); }, 2000);
    }, function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $(this).removeClass("door doorstatic");
    }
);
```

Comment: `addClass` doesn´t accept a second string argument like "slow".

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can just append a call to [jQuery's delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to you `addClass` call.

Something like

```
 $(this).addClass("door").delay(2000).addClass("doorstatic", "slow");
```

should do the trick.

Comment: There's no second argument in the addClass-method. And I don't think delay will work there.

Comment: @OptimusCrime ~ jQuery UI extends the `.addClass()` method (along with a handful of others) to support animation. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/addClass